# How can I achieve BottomNavigationBar with 1 NavigationBarItem

Tags: flutter

I want a BottomNavigationBar with 1 NavigationBarItem. The purpose is to display a record count for a list.

Can someone please advise me if there is a way to achieve that?

I can see no logical reason why the "items:" must exceed 1 item, but I'd be pleased to learn why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to handle this and the way that I ended up using is to add an invisible BottomNavigationBarItem to the BottomNavigationBar. The way to do that is to just use icon: Icon(null) and an zero-length text. The reason that at least two items are needed in the BottomNavigationBar is possibly because of the docking capability of the FAB button which is a very useful feature.

Answer (score 1):

Into `bottomNavigationBar` need to minimun 2 NavigationBarItem require. but you want a BottomNavigationBar with 1 NavigationBarItem, So you can use the Custom layout for the BottomNavigationBarItem for display 1 item into bottomNavigationBar

Custom Layout like as bellow :

```
bottomNavigationBar: Container(
        height: 65,
        color: Colors.grey,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.list),
                onPressed: (){},
              ),
              Text("items"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Thanks, that pretty much emulates what I want (I used a Row). I will accept it. Any idea why the BottomNavigationBar insists on a minimum of 2 items? I cannot understand why.